# .next() and .scrollLeft()

Tags: jquery

I would like the document to scrollLeft to the next image every time I press the "next" link.

[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/josiahmccracken/pgeQR/) is my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Change `top` to `left`:

```
scrollLeft: $current.offset().left
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgeQR/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the jQuery's `css` feature has a `scrollLeft` As Joseph said, you must change `left` to `top`.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pgeQR/1/